Is it possible to set an inflated password column with DBIx::Class::PassphraseColumn as undef / NULL?
I'm using DBIx::Class::PassphraseColumn to hash passwords with Authen::Passphrase::BlowfishCrypt, which works well.  However, I'm trying to use the same on a couple of other columns (password reset key / activation key), which should both be nulled after the user has activated / the password has been reset, I'm hitting an error.
The columns are set here:
__PACKAGE__->add_columns(
    "password" => {
        data_type => "text",
        is_nullable => 0,
        passphrase => "rfc2307",
        passphrase_class => "BlowfishCrypt",
        passphrase_args => {
          cost => 14,
          salt_random => 1,
        },
        passphrase_check_method => "check_password",
    },
    "activation_key" => {
        data_type => "text",
        is_nullable => 1,
        passphrase => "rfc2307",
        passphrase_class => "BlowfishCrypt",
        passphrase_args => {
          cost => 14,
          salt_random => 1,
        },
        passphrase_check_method => "check_act_key",
    },
    "password_reset_key" => {
        data_type => "text",
        is_nullable => 1,
        passphrase => "rfc2307",
        passphrase_class => "BlowfishCrypt",
        passphrase_args => {
          cost => 14,
          salt_random => 1,
        },
        passphrase_check_method => "check_password_reset_key",
    }
);

The error is:

[error] Caught exception in TopTable::Controller::Users->activate "hash not specified at D:/Personal/Dev/Perl/perl/site/lib/DBIx/Class/PassphraseColumn.pm line 173."

The update code is here:
$self->update({
    activated => 1,
    activation_key => undef,
    activation_expires => undef,
});

If I set the activation key to an empty string, this works but leaves a hashed value - I can live with that for now, but really I'd like to be able to NULL the column if that's possible.
Am I being totally stupid?
Thanks!

Could you provide a minimal runnable example? This could help clarify your question. See [mcve] for more information
